# How to read a body of received aws-ses email

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns, amazon-route53, amazon-ses

I want to set up [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) service for receiving and processing technical emails from different subscriptions.

I read documentation [Setting Up Amazon SES Email Receiving](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-setting-up.html) and followed all steps.

For receiving a body I tried both ways:

- Storing an email to S3 storage.
- Sending an email via SNS service.

But in both cases, I get the message that my service's configuration isn't completed.

The message looks like:

*Please note that the rule that you configured to deliver emails to this S3 bucket is only valid if the entire setup process is successful. For more information about
setting up email-receiving rules, see the Amazon SES Developer Guide at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/Welcome.html .*

If I got correct I have to transfer my domain to [Route 53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) service.

But it isn't the best option for me. Because I have the special price for registering/prolongation from my provider. Moreover, I registered my domain a few days ago and need to wait one month before I will be able to transfer it (according to my provider rules).

In the current moment, I can get subject, sender, receiver, date and so on information from a mail, except the body.

Do I really have to wait one month and transfer my domain to Route 53? Or I missed something?

**EDIT:** I read comments to this post and repeat all steps from the first document. I don't know what I did wrong yesterday but I am receiving mail as expected now.

Comment: I don't think Route 53 is of any importance here. DNS is only used to find your server on the internet. And given that you receive subject/sender/etc, you seems to be receiving the e-mail. So, your DNS records seem to be ok.  I don't see Amazon documentation to require it either - it says it's "easier" to set up with Route 53,  but does not say it is required. However, DKIM is likely important.

Comment: subject/sender/etc, but no body, seems rather like a notification about the email, not actual e-mail. Keep in mind that only SNS action will deliver complete e-mails to your SNS topic. Other actions can notify you via SNS about e-mails, but they won't put actual e-mail to SNS. In fact, I suspect what you're receiving at the moment are actually notifications about e-mail delivery failures (caused by the error you mentioned in the question).

Comment: I believe @Seva is correct on both counts.  Additionally, you are confusing domain registration and DNS hosting.  Your domain can remain registered with your current registrar yet hosted on Route 53 by creating a hosted zone and changing the authoritative nameservers at the registrar to point to it.  This can be changed at any time, regardless of how recently the domain was registered and there is no need to transfer the domain.  But also, there's no real need to use Route 53 hosting, either... it just makes the setup simpler.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the verification process might not have fully completed at the time. Once the MX, TXT and CNAME records have been added to your DNS settings and had enough time to propagate, everything should work as expected. If it takes too long, ensure there are no typos in the record names/values.

For others with this problem, ensure the domain shows as fully verified in the `SES Home > Domains` section. I just went through this, so hope it helps.